# How to overload the ternary operator (?:) in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How to overload this comparison operator in C++?

```
(statement)?(if true):(if false)
```

Comment: It's not possible to overload the ternary operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't (§13.5/3):

> The following operators cannot be overloaded:
>   `.`    `.*`   `::`    `?:`
>   nor can the preprocessing symbols
>   `#`
>   and
>   `##`
>   (Clause
>    16).